# Input buttons remain unformatted

Tags: html, css, button

I have a very peculiar problem concerning formatted input buttons.

On my first page, I created a css rule named "button" for formatting buttons that stand alone in one row. it works perfectly, and the button appears as shown below

[image]

the css for this button is below

```
.button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15mm;
    background-color: #AAA;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #888;
    border:none; !important
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 0px 0px #888, 0px -2px 0px 0px #DDD;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #888, 0px -2px 0px 0px #DDD;
    box-shadow:         0px 2px 0px 0px #888, 0px -2px 0px 0px #DDD;

}
```

In html, it looks like this:

```
<a href="dashboard.html">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="SUBMIT" action="dashboard.html" />
</a>
```

The problem is, I've copied this rule and altered it slightly in a second page for buttons which are parallel, and it doesn't format the buttons. strangely enough, it appears right in dreamweaver

[image]

but in any browser, it loses it's formatting

[image]

Here is the css for the parallel buttons

```
.2buttons {
    width: 40%;
    height: 15mm;
    background-color: #AAA;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #888;
    border:none; !important
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 0px 0px #888, 0px -2px 0px 0px #DDD;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #888, 0px -2px 0px 0px #DDD;
    box-shadow:         0px 2px 0px 0px #888, 0px -2px 0px 0px #DDD;

}
```

and here is the html

```
<a href="report.html">
  <input class="2buttons" type="button" value="OK"/>
</a>
```

strangely enough, even if you apply the first css rule, which works, to these buttons, they still remain unformatted.

Comment: Rename the second class to "buttons2". class and id selectors cannot start with a number.

Comment: I guess it is because of first digit in class name. Try twoButtons instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There two thing in your code.

**first** 
Never start **class** &**ID** name with numerical number.

Write like this **.buttons2** instead of this **.2buttons**.

**& Second**

Write like this

```
border:none !important;
```

Instead of this:

```
border:none; !important
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I can't believe I didn't know that until now

Answer (score 1):

`border:none; !important` should be `border:none !important;`

And change the class name to .twoButtons (or something else) instead of .2buttons as class names can't start with numbers...

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT start a class name with a number! This is only supported in Internet Explorer.
See

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp

Comment: thanks, can't believe I didn't know that before now *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

Your problem in that the name of the class starts with number. You should change that.